# Python specific vaules average of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```py
{201001: '-28.3', 201002: '-23.8', 201003: '-24.2', 201004: '-14.1',
 201005: '-7.5', 201006: '0.1', 201007: '5.0', 201008: '5.6',
 201009: '2.6', 201010: '-5.0', 201011: '-12.1', 201012: '-23.6',
 201101: '-23.0', 201102: '-21.7', 201103: '-21.9', 201104: '-19.5',
 201105: '-6.0', 201106: '0.7', 201107: '4.8', 201108: '5.2',
 201109: '2.3', 201110: '-4.9', 201111: '-18.5', 201112: '-23.8'}
```

This dictionary represents the temperature of Alaska.
`201001: '-28.3'` represent temperature of Alaska in 2010 January is -28.3 celsius.)

I want to get the average temperature of winter year by year which is

`( January’s + February’s ) / 2`.

For example 2010's winter average temperature is `(-28.3 + -23.8) / 2`.

I think seeing and directly typing average year by year isn't elegant because there are more years 2000~2019.

(I typed only 2 years 2010,2011 for readability.) 
How to get average of specific data year by year in dictionary?

Comment: I feel like using ints to represent dates is a bad idea. Strings would probably be better, if not some [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) type.

Comment: If you are happy to define the average temperature as `(January's + February's) / 2`, then okay, but from a scientific point of view it would make more sense to weight each of them by the length of the month concerned. Given also that the length of February may vary with year (albeit there are no leap years in your example data), this is a somewhat more difficult problem than the one you originally asked, but you might consider asking it nonetheless.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Have you tried breaking down the problem on paper, writing pseudocode, etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temperature by Year

```
by_year = {}
for k, v in d.items():
  # k // 100 is year
  by_year.setdefault(k //100, []).append(float(v))
```

Average Temperature in Winter

```
avg_winter = {}
for k, months in by_year.items():
    # months[:2] to average first two months
    avg_winter[k] = sum(months[:2])/len(months[:2])
```

**Output**

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(by_year)
pprint(avg_winter)

by_year

{2010: [-28.3,
        -23.8,
        -24.2,
        -14.1,
        -7.5,
        0.1,
        5.0,
        5.6,
        2.6,
        -5.0,
        -12.1,
        -23.6],
 2011: [-23.0,
        -21.7,
        -21.9,
        -19.5,
        -6.0,
        0.7,
        4.8,
        5.2,
        2.3,
        -4.9,
        -18.5,
        -23.8]}

avg_winter

{2010: -26.05, 2011: -22.35}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple loop should do it, no?

```py
from typing import Dict
def avg_winter_temps(temps: Dict[int, float]) -> Dict[int, float]:
    winter_temps = {}
    for year in range(2010, 2019+1):
        jan, feb = year*100 + 1, year*100 + 2
        winter_temps[year] = (temps[jan] + temps[feb])/2
    return winter_temps
```

Comment: Because I'm beginner, It requires time to understand for me... thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to find keys that end in "01" or "02":

```
import re
dictionary = {201001: '-28.3', 201002: '-23.8', 201003: '-24.2', 201004: '-14.1',
 201005: '-7.5', 201006: '0.1', 201007: '5.0', 201008: '5.6',
 201009: '2.6', 201010: '-5.0', 201011: '-12.1', 201012: '-23.6',
 201101: '-23.0', 201102: '-21.7', 201103: '-21.9', 201104: '-19.5',
 201105: '-6.0', 201106: '0.7', 201107: '4.8', 201108: '5.2',
 201109: '2.3', 201110: '-4.9', 201111: '-18.5', 201112: '-23.8'}
key_list = dictionary.keys()
months = 0
sum = 0
averages = []
for key in key_list:
    match = re.search("01$|02$", str(key)) # String ends in '01; or in '02'
    if match:
        if months == 0:
            sum += float(dictionary.get(key))
            months += 1
        else:
            sum += float(dictionary.get(key))
            months = 0
            averages.append(sum / 2)
            sum = 0
print(averages)
```

Output:

```
[-26.05, -22.35]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended as an answer to the question asked, but to supplement the existing answers if you want to take into account that to calculate a time average of temperature over the January-February period the monthly averages should be weighted by the lengths of the months concerned.  The function `calc_jan_feb_average` can be used to calculate this weighted average.  It requires the year as an input parameter because of leap years.

```
import datetime

def get_length_feb(year):
    return (datetime.datetime(year, 3, 1)
            - datetime.datetime(year, 2, 1)).total_seconds()

def calc_jan_feb_average(year, jan_temp, feb_temp):
    length_jan = 31 * 86400
    length_feb = get_length_feb(year)

    return (
        ((jan_temp * length_jan) + (feb_temp * length_feb)) /
        (length_jan + length_feb)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
temps = {201001: '-28.3', 201002: '-23.8', 201003: '-24.2', 201004: '-14.1',
         201005: '-7.5', 201006: '0.1', 201007: '5.0', 201008: '5.6',
         201009: '2.6', 201010: '-5.0', 201011: '-12.1', 201012: '-23.6',
         201101: '-23.0', 201102: '-21.7', 201103: '-21.9', 201104: '-19.5',
         201105: '-6.0', 201106: '0.7', 201107: '4.8', 201108: '5.2',
         201109: '2.3', 201110: '-4.9', 201111: '-18.5', 201112: '-23.8'}

avgs = {}
jan = min(temps.keys()) // 100 * 100 + 1
limit = max(temps.keys())
while jan <= limit:
    jt = temps.get(jan)
    feb = jan + 1
    ft = temps.get(feb)
    if jt is not None and ft is not None:
        avgs[f'{jan} - {feb}'] = (float(jt) + float(ft)) / 2
    jan += 100

for period, avg in avgs.items():
    print(f'{period} = {avg}')
```

Output:

```
201001 - 201002 = -26.05
201101 - 201102 = -22.35
```